# Show plot for specific time period with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data for Nasdaq index from 1985 to 2022, I was wondering if it was possible to show a plot for a given period instead of whole. So from like 1990 to 2005?

This is the code I have written so far.

```
Nasdaq19852022 %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Date,y=Close)) +
labs(title = "NASDAQ index prices",
   
   subtitle = "End of Month Index Prices",
   caption = " Source: Eikon") +

xlab("Date") + ylab("Total Return") +
scale_color_manual(values = c("Black"))+
geom_line()
```

[image: Current graph]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A: You have two straightforward approaches:

1. Filter your dataset before plotting to the desired dates
2. On your plot, limit the `x` axis to the desired dates. Note that on this approach, your field `Date` must be a date object.

```r
library(tidyBdE)
library(ggplot2)
# I use here the IBEX-35 Index (since you didn't provide your data)
ibex <- bde_series_load("254433", "Close")

ibex %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Close)) +
  labs(
    title = "IBEX index prices",
    subtitle = "End of Month Index Prices",
    caption = " Source: Bank of Spain"
  ) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Total Return") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Black")) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```r
# First approach: Filter out the dataset
ibex %>%
  filter(Date >= "1990-01-01" & Date <= "2005-12-31") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Close)) +
  labs(
    title = "IBEX index prices",
    subtitle = "End of Month Index Prices",
    caption = " Source: Bank of Spain"
  ) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Total Return") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Black")) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```r
# Second approach: Filter the plot on the scales
# Same result
ibex %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Close)) +
  labs(
    title = "IBEX index prices",
    subtitle = "End of Month Index Prices",
    caption = " Source: Bank of Spain"
  ) +
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("1990-01-01", "2005-12-31"))) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Total Return") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Black")) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]